# Angular Momentum of an orbital and orbit

Tags: atomic-structure

While pursuing forth in Atomic Structure, I encountered the following concepts...

According to Bohr, the angular momentum of an *orbit* remains quantized, i.e $\displaystyle mvr = n\hbar .$

But he wasn't able to expalin the reason that why is it so.

---

But later *Louis de Broglie* gave his hypothesis:

*Every particle in the universe has dual nature, one wave nature an other particle nature.*

Focusing on wave nature of particle he gave an equation, known as **de Broglie equation** or **de Broglie wavelength** as

$$\displaystyle \lambda = \frac {h}{mv}.$$

This was proved years later by *Davisson and Germer's Diffraction Experiment.*

---

Now, we can also prove the quantization of angular momentum of an orbit as:

For any orbit the number of waves produced by an electron in one complete revolution is $\displaystyle \frac {2\pi r}{\lambda}.$

Substituting the values of $r,v$ given by Bohr, then

$$\displaystyle \frac {2\pi r}{\lambda} = \frac {2\pi r \cdot mv}{h} = \frac { n^2 \hbar^2 \cdot mkZe^2}{\hbar \cdot mkZe^2 \cdot n\hbar} = n$$

As $\displaystyle r =\frac { n^2 \hbar^2 }{ mkZe^2}  $ and $\displaystyle v = \frac {kZe^2}{ n\hbar}.$

Now , as $ \displaystyle \frac {2\pi r}{\lambda}= n ,$ From this we can prove that angualr momentum of an orbit is quantized.

---

Now according to Quantum wave mechanical model, the angular orbital momentum of an orbital is : $ \displaystyle \sqrt {l(l+1)} \hbar .$

Now which one is actually valid, because in many of the books both of the momentums are refered only by the term *angular momentum.*  But both are not same.

My question might sound silly, for such topic... But I would like to know which one is to be refered when we encounter angular momentum.

Comment: Seriously, erase the Bohr model from your brain. It is scientifically *wrong.* Its only use is giving us a glimpse into how quantum mechanics developed historically.

Comment: Ok, means we have to consider Quantum wave mechanical model whenever angular momentum is refered... Thank you.

Comment: Yep. The Bohr model *did* manage to get some things right, but those were essentially by coincidence. Electrons simply *don't* move in a circular "orbit" around the nucleus.

Comment: @orthocresol what is the significance of angular momentum in quantum model when electron does not got in circular motion?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande, even classically, angular momentum is simply the cross product of position and momentum: $\mathbf{l} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$. It is not something that is exclusive to uniform circular motion. The same is true of quantum angular momentum, except that $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ are operators.

Comment: @orthocresol  got it. thank you so much! Any good reading matter you can suggest in understanding quantum model of an atom?... Would be a great help

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande My suggestion is to read an actual QM book, and by that I mean a physics one. In my opinion, (notwithstanding [the famous Feynman quote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3ZRLllWgHI)) one needs to "understand" QM itself before they can "understand" QM as applied to atoms. I learnt from Griffiths' *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, but there are many texts out there. You don't need to follow it through to the end with all the advanced topics, but getting the basics right is really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bohr Model came before the quantum theory and it was a success for explaining the non- continuous emission spectrum of excited hydrogen atoms. However, Bohr model was not sufficient for explaining many other phenomena related to the interaction of matter with light, such as the non-continuous  emission spectrum of multi-electronic atoms,  Zeeman Effect,... Therefore, the quantum theory is considered as a more complete theory.
The quantification of the angular orbital momentum should be linked to the second quantum number $l$ not $n$.

Up till now, we use Bohr model in chemistry textbooks in spite of its limitation. This is because it's simple and doesn't require complex mathematical tools as quantum theory.

Comment: Ok, I agree to that. But my question is that when de Broglie hypothesis can prove consevation of angular momentum and the Schrodinger's equation also satisfies the  de Broglie hypothesis, then why we do not consider $\displaystyle mvr = n\hbar $ ?

Comment: The Bohr Model does not account for the fact that accelerating electrons do not emit electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I understood the situtation..

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew that...

Comment: The circular trajectory of  the orbit is also an error. This is only true for Bohr model.

Comment: I am happy that I helped you.

Comment: Yes, I agree to that, there are no orbits, rather orbitals...